# What is the alternative of SqlConnection to connect data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, odata, sqlconnection

Let me apologize in advance if this question is already answered.

Let me explain my situation: I have two servers, Server A & Server B and I need to sync the SQL Server on them using Microsoft Sync Framework.

Server A is within my organization network and protected by organization security policy (firewall etc) and the Server B is outside our network.

My sync app sits in a workstation that is within our company's network and has internet connection. This app can access web services installed in Server B, but due to our organization's policy it cannot connect to the SQL Server in Server B via `SqlConnection` (.NET) or Management Studio.

Now is there any way where I can connect the SQL Server in Server B other than `SqlConnection`? Is there any possibility to connect by exposing through web service?

I was googling and it seems OData in WCF could be a solution. What's your opinion on this as well.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, a SQL connection is required to retrieve data from a SQL Server database.  Since you cannot connect directly from inside your organization, that SQL connection will need to be in a service layer that either resides on Server B or on a server that can establish a database connection to Server B.

OData, WCF, etc. could be used as the service layer.  However, any recommendation I provide would be opinion-based and therefore off-topic here.  I suggest you use whichever technology you are most comfortable with or want to learn.

Comment: Yes, I do need to use SQL connection at server B to expose the data to app in Server A. And probably the OData is the answer. The difficulty I am facing is that there isn't much example in OData or Microsoft Sync Framework's Web Feed. So far I haven't found much resources to work with so I am looking for any suggestion that is available.

Comment: For an OData example and explanation, take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/393623/OData-Services.